# Simple Database Query Button

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

OK, I've completely given up.  I'm trying to write what should be a simple query from in an asp.net C# web page using Visual Studio 2017.  For the life of me, I can't figure out what's going wrong, and I can't find an answer (that I understand) anywhere.  So I need help.

I have an asp button (ID=submit) on my form and one text box (ID=textbox1). The connectionstring per my SQL data source is

```
Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =| DataDirectory |\TheList.mdb
```

How the hell can I get the submit button to run an SQL query that searches the value of textbox1 against my database field "Name" and display the results in a FormView.

I want/need to learn this, so I appreciate any helpful links, but damned if I haven't been googling this every which-way for 2 solid weeks now, so I'd also be happy with some basic code.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to give more information. What have you tried? What DB you connecting to?

Comment: Just create a simple onclick() event inside it use stored Procedure Or a Query  which will return a value. Then assign that value to the Textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a simple onclick() event inside it use stored Procedure Or a Query which will return a value. Then assign that value to the Textbox 
In `.aspx`

```
<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit"/>
```

now in `.aspx.cs`

```
protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetFruitName", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FruitId", int.Parse(txtFruitId.Text.Trim()));
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FruitName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
            cmd.Parameters["@FruitName"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            lblFruitName.Text = "Fruit Name: " + cmd.Parameters["@FruitName"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

refer [this Link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-return-Output-parameter-from-Stored-Procedure-in-ASPNet-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx)  for further refference

Comment: check the Link out it is explained properly as u said "I want/need to learn this," this might help you understanding the concept

Comment: I also ran across a page that I had previously tried, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw738475.aspx.   I may have had something added to the button_click code previously that stopped it from working, but once I removed the bad code, this method also worked